# Loading font for three js 3d text

Tags: javascript, fonts, three.js

I am trying to use a simple piece of code to render 3d text but getting error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/<name>/threejs/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = '';

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

    // your code here
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          color: 0xdddddd
        });
        var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello World!', {
          font: '' // Must be lowercase!
        });
        var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeom, material );

        scene.add( textMesh );

        // Do some optional calculations. This is only if you need to get the
        // width of the generated text
        textGeom.computeBoundingBox();
        textGeom.textWidth = textGeom.boundingBox.max.x - textGeom.boundingBox.min.x;

} );
```

This seems to be a common issue just from googling this but don't understand what's different with my code.

I even tried following this http://blog.andrewray.me/creating-a-3d-font-in-three-js/ where they import the font with `<script src="your-font.typeface.js"></script>` but that isn't working for me either. I get an error `elvetiker_regular.typeface.json:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe `font: '' // Must be lowercase!` should be `font: font`, as you get the `font` from your callback function and, in accordance to the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/TextGeometry), you have to put it in the parameters of `THREE.TextGeometry()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: Also read "[How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/How-to-run-thing-locally)" in the three.js documentation.

Comment: @PeterO. should add that as an answer..